# How do I add data posted to admin-ajax.php into a database?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am fairly new to WordPress and would like some guidance on best practice. I am using a plugin which is posting data to admin-ajax.php.

I would like to add this data to a MySql database.

Am I able to use WPCode snippet on the page that posts the data to do this?